# Typescript Type has no property in common with type

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a weak dependency error in typescript.

> Type Headers has no properties in common with type..

I am trying to send post and delete request to another api for 2 different methods.
my ts code in service have 2 different method, the first one "addcustomer" is working without problem but second "deletecustomer" is not,

```
addcustomer(customer: string, disable: boolean): Observable<customer> {
    const newAddcustomerModel = {
      customer: customer, disable: disable
    } as AddcustomerModel;

    return this.http.post<customer>(`/api/admin/add-customers`, newAddcustomerModel);
  }

  deletecustomer(id: number): Observable<customer> {
    const newcustomerModel = {
      id: id
    } as DeletecustomerModel;

    return this.http.delete<customer>(`/api/admin/delete-customers`, newcustomerModel)
  }
```

and models for them

```
export interface AddCustomerModel {
  customer: string;
  disable: boolean;
}
```

and for second one is:

```
export interface DeleteCustomerModel {
  id: number;
}
```

The error is on **newcustomerModel** which is in **deletecustomer()** method at last line.

[image]

Comment: Spelling mistake in your code: DeletecustomerModel should be DeleteCustomerModel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create `HttpHeaders` instance to allocate the headers

```
let newcustomerModel = new HttpHeaders({
  id: id
} )

this.http.delete<customer>(`/api/admin/delete-customers`, {headers: newcustomerModel })
```

Comment: i am sending the newcustomerModel as message body, is it still ok for it ?

Comment: so do i have to make it post method ?

Comment: if u want to send a body then yeah